# Publishing user's activities from Facebook App

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am developing a Facebook application, and I am trying to publish the users' activites in my application in the user's wall, like when the user comments on post, the story feedback appears in his wall and is available to his friends to see

I have read these tutorials:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

As well as the following threads:

[How to publish Actions to Facebook Graph API with parameters in call URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982416/how-to-publish-actions-to-facebook-graph-api-with-parameters-in-call-url)

[Facebook- Publishing a story to user's wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309264/facebook-publishing-a-story-to-users-wall)

I am confused about which one I should follow because openGraph seems a bit complicated to implement....so what is the best practice to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to post activities on users wall, open graph is preferred way and you will get large distribution(marketing) also.

You can use the [PHP Official sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) from facebook, which makes you job easier.

To post open graph actions, you should take `publish_actions` [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#extended_perms) from user.

or

You can post on user's wall using `/me/feed` method requires `[publish_stream][3]` extended permission.

***SDK tutorial***

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

***Open graph sample application***
Download Social Cafe app and see their code
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/samples/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) as well, and sometimes that is actually getting better. For example, recently Facebook enforces that users have to read for at least 10 seconds before the app publishes `news:Read`. These are the usecases that can be handled very efficiently with javascript sdk and jquery (or similar client-side technology).

Answer (score 0):

As for April 2018,
The `publish_actions` permission is no longer available.